# Java maven Junit read systemproperties variable to load property file

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, maven-3

Java Maven Spring Junit with webapplication

I am using following code to load property file into spring context placer holder.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${RESOURCE_PATH}/jdbc.properties" />
```

in eclipse Junit run time configuration i have defined "RESOURCE_PATH" so it runs fine when i execute my junit tests from GUI but when i run from maven they fail.

Can we define variable and pass in pom file at run time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either supply the property `RESOURCE_PATH` using `-D` switch when running maven or put it into `pom.xml` into section `<properties>`; something like this:

```
<properties>
    <RESOURCE_PATH>put your path here</RESOURCE_PATH>
</properties>
```

Comment: i want it to available only for test cases